# Unable to read Inherited class instances with DataNucles JDO

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I was unable to read the full inherited class instances as described in following URL

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/orm/inheritance.html

Following describes the mapping of classes.

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
@Discriminator(strategy=DiscriminatorStrategy.CLASS_NAME)
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceStrategy.NEW_TABLE)
public class IdeaItem {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Column(jdbcType = "INTEGER", length = 11)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="IDEAID")
    private Idea idea;

    @Column(jdbcType = "INTEGER", length = 11)
    private long showOrder;

 }

 @PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true") 
 @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceStrategy.NEW_TABLE)
 public class IdeaItemText extends IdeaItem {

    @Column(jdbcType = "VARCHAR", length = 500) 
    private String text;

 }
```

Data saving part working fine. I inserted "IdeaItemText" object and both "IdeaItem" and "IdeaItemText" tables got updated successfully.

Now I need to read Subclasses by putting "IdeaItem" as an Extent. I executed the following code.

```
 Extent items = getPersistenceManager().getExtent(IdeaItem.class,true);
 javax.jdo.Query q = getPersistenceManager().newQuery(items);
 List data = (List)q.execute();
```

As in the JDO docs, this should return the whole object graph. But this is not returning any record. When I check the log, I found that it searching for a reacord where Discriminator Value equals to "com.mydomain.IdeaItem" which does not exists. When I removed the Discriminator annotation I got all the records in the table. Even though how I access the sub classes attributes ? Furthermore how I query subclass attributes with the base class Extent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you didn't let the persistence mechanism know about the subclass (whether that is using auto-start mechanism, persistence.xml, calling pm.getExtent on the subclass, or simply instantiating the subclass.class). It can only query classes that it is "aware of"

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is that mean I cannot use Base Class as the extent and use the "instanceof" operator in java to cast object ? According to your answer what I understood is, first I have to get Id's using IdeaItem and then again I have to manually issue a select command to each subtype. is this correct ?

Comment: i didnt say anything of the sort. I said you have to use either persistence.xml, autostartmechanism, or those other things so JDO knows about your subclass. You then issue the query ... and it knows about those classes.

Comment: Really sorry about getting late to reply. I'm still unable to find a solution for this. I'm using spring to initiate PersistentManagerFactory. So I do not having persistent.xml. So is there a  way to pragmatically make persistent manager aware about my sub classes ? If do, can you please provide a code sample ?

Comment: "autostart" is a simple persistence property config option, easily findable in DataNucleus docs. If Spring can't work with "persistence.xml" with JDO then that is a flaw in Spring, and suggest you raise a bug in Spring for that

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think I found the issue with this. The discriminator column only usable under a Flat table. So I guess If I want JDO retrieve subclasses automatically, I have to use the "Superclass table" Inheritance strategy.